# Python: How can I get a list of function names from within __getattr__ function?

Tags: python

How can I get the list of class functions from within `__getattr__` function?

Python v2.7 if it matters.

Trying to use `dir` within `__getattr__` leads to infinite recursion.

```
class Hal(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print 'I don\'t have a %s function' % name
        names = dir(self) # <-- infinite recursion happens here
        print 'My functions are: %s' % ', '.join(names)
        exit()
    def close_door(self):
        pass
x = Hal()       
x.open_door()
```

Here's the output I want:

```
I don't have a open_door function
My functions are: close_door, __getattr__, __init__, __doc__, ...
```

Any other solution which gets me the output I want will work fine.  I want to do fuzzy string matching in the case when a function doesn't exist to try to suggest what the user might have meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is there any reason why you can't do this?

```
names = dir(self.__class__)
```

are you expecting consumers to extend instances of Hal to have custom methods?

if you only want methods you've implemented, with no built-ins listed, you could try this too:

```
names = [prop for prop in dir(self.__class__) if prop[1] != "_"]
```

Comment: That works, thanks!  I had assumed `dir(self)` and `dir(Hal)` would perform the same, since I don't have any special `__setattr__` stuff happening.  Knowledge acquired.

Answer (score 3):

This works I think:

```
import types

class Hal(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print ('I don\'t have a %s function' % name)
        funcs = (name for name,func in self.__class__.__dict__.items() if isinstance(func,types.FunctionType))

        #names = dir(self) # <-- infinite recursion happens here
        print ('My functions are: %s' % ', '.join(str(f) for f in funcs))
        exit()

    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        pass

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        pass

    def qux(self):
        pass

    def close_door(self):
        pass

x = Hal()
x.foo = 'bar'
x.open_door()
```

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- Yeah.  I was writing it up when yours still said `self.__dict__`.  It seems that you've corrected that in the mean-time.  +1 to yours for being here first.

Comment: I don't think `FunctionType` is what you want here. This will return True for static methods, False for instance methods.

Comment: @abarnert -- from my tests, this removes `staticmethod` and `classmethod` decorated functions, but passes through un-decorated functions (see updated code).  The decorated functions are actually descriptors, so they're probably of type: `types.InstanceType` or something similar.  I'm not exactly sure how to get those ones reliably (without getting other stuff).

Comment: @mgilson: Sorry, I didn't realize you were getting the values out of `self.__class__.__dict__`. In that case, unbound instance methods are functions, you're right. It's when you get the `dir` and do `getattr(self.__class__, name)` or equivalent that you get the method-wrapper objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
names = self.__class__.__dict__
```

possibly?

```
>>> class A:
...   def hello(self,x):
...       print "hello ",x
...   def my_dir(self):
...       print self.__class__.__dict__
...
>>> A().my_dir()
{'__module__': '__main__', 'my_dir': <function my_dir at 0x029A5AB0>, 'hello': <
 function hello at 0x029A5CB0>, '__doc__': None}
```

Comment: probably filtering the `values` with `types.MethodType` or something of that sort.

Comment: `A.__dict__` does, `self.__dict__` does not.

Comment: @devtk -- good point, but I suppose you could filter `self.__class__.__dict__`

Comment: you would need `self.__class__.__dict__` I guess

Comment: In which case, you also need to filter on `types.FunctionType` as they're not bound methods when they're attached to the class's dictionary.

Comment: yeah but i figured id leave something for OP to do :P

Comment: @Joran Yes, that's fine I can filter the methods myself.  :)  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make a copy of the `dir` before adding the `__getattr__` method:

```
class Hal(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._names = dir(self)
        def __getattr__(self, name):
            print self.names
        self.__getattr__ = __getattr__
```

However, for simple cases, you can just call `dir` (and likewise `getattr`, or `inspect.getmembers`, or whatever) on your class object to solve the problem. This doesn't work if instance can have methods added after construction, but if that's not an issue, it's easy:

```
names = dir(self.__class__)
```

However you get the names, to filter for methods, there are a few things to do.

First, you can use `isinstance` on `getattr(self, name)` and make sure it's a method-wrapper (or get the type of the bound version and make sure it's an instancemethod). If you get the values directly out of `self.__class__.__dict__`, you don't get exactly the same thing as if you get the names in your favorite way and call either `getattr(self, name)` or `getattr(self.__class__, name)`. In particular, an instance method will show up as a `function`, which is easier to test for than a method-wrapper. Although some of the other cases now get harder to detect.

At any rate, nothing based on type will find things that act like methods but aren't (e.g., because you've assigned a built-in function directly to the object, wrapped something in certain kinds of decorators, written custom descriptors, used a class with a `__callable__` method as a function, etc.). If you're doing anything fancy (or worry that someone might later add something fancy), you really need to test whether you can explicitly bind the member (or fake-bind it to `None`), and then check if the result is `callable`, and then possibly do further tests to make sure it's callable properly (because otherwise you'll get fooled by `@staticmethod`s and similar things). Really, if this comes up (and you've really thought through your design and convinced yourself and at least one other person that it isn't insane…), you should test everything you can think of against every case you have…

If you want to know if the methods are defined in `Hal` or the instance as opposed to `object` or another base class, there are a few ways to do this, but the simplest is to just subtract out the members of the base classes. (Of course if you don't care about methods defined in the instance, `Hal.__dict__` already has what you want.)